# Implement PAT for a certain associated type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Assume, you have a PAT:

```
protocol PAT {
    associatedtype T
    func provide() -> T
}
```

And another protocol, that uses that protocol as a type constraint:

```
protocol RegularProtocol {
    func consume<P: PAT>(_ pat: P) -> P.T
}
```

Is there a way to implement that second protocol for a certain associated type of PAT? For example, it would be great to have it if it were possible something like:

```
struct Consumer: RegularProtocol /*!*/ where RegularProtocol.T == () /*!*/ {
    func consume<P: PAT>(_ pat: P)  {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I haven't found a way to do anything similar and am assuming that architecrure re-thinking is needed. But anyway, is there something I've missed?

Any advice on dealing with such situations is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to add an `associatedType` to `RegularProtocol`:

```
protocol PAT {
    associatedtype T
    func provide() -> T
}

protocol RegularProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func consume<P: PAT>(_ pat: P) -> T where P.T == T
}

struct Consumer: RegularProtocol {
    typealias T = Int
    func consume<P: PAT>(_ pat: P) -> T where P.T == T {
      return pat.provide() * 10
    }
}
```

Note that `RegularProtocol` without associated type would have to accept all `PAT` types, therefore you cannot implement it partially just for some types.

Comment: I guess, this approach will fit my needs! Thank you very much!